# How to replace "Nan" missing values with "?" while preserving the pattern?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Question:** Looking at the data set below, the data set has a pattern that every four "Nan" will have two values (dtypes = float64) sandwich one "Nan". The pattern repeats till where the N-2 and N index positions should also contain values like before. But there is none, I want some code that can detect the pattern and place "?" at the indexes that have missing values. All other "Nan" should stay as "Nan". Because they will be dropped later all together, I don't want to drop the places that have missing values too. (N is total index number) **How should I do this?**

I have a pandas data frame that contains the following data set:

```
    0 Nan
    1 Nan
    2 Nan
    3 Nan
    4 24.289
    5 Nan
    6 24.153
    7 Nan
    8 Nan
    9 Nan
   10 Nan
   11 24.02
   12 Nan
   13 23.915
   14 Nan
   15 Nan
   16 Nan
   17 Nan
   18 22.479
   19 Nan
   20 22.68
      .
      .
      .
   40 Nan <-- Missing value that needs to be replaced with "?"
   41 Nan
   42 Nan <-- Missing value that needs to be replaced with "?"
      .
      .
      .
  N-2 Nan     
  N-1 Nan
   N  Nan
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
    df.dropna()
    df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This code drops all "Nan" in the data frame. Index 40 and 42 are just an example of where the data might be missing. In other words, these two missing values can be anywhere in the data frame but the pattern remains. They will never be in places where the four "Nan" are or breaking the pattern mentioned above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's find all the groups of 7 rows that meet the desired condition (a null value at the 5th and 7th position):

```
>>> groups_that_meet_condition = df.groupby(df.index // 7).filter(lambda group: group.iloc[4, 1] is None and group.iloc[6, 1] is None)
```

Now, let's fill the the NaN values at the 5th and 7th position using `.fillna("?")`, bot only looking at the first group (meaning, up to the 7th space):

```
>>> groups_that_meet_condition[4:7:7] = groups_that_meet_condition.iloc[4:7:7].fillna("?")
>>> groups_that_meet_condition[6:7:7] = groups_that_meet_condition.iloc[6:7:7].fillna("?")
```

Finally, let's fill our original dataframe rows with the modified version:

```
>>> df.loc[groups_that_meet_condition.index] = groups_that_meet_condition
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use your index (assuming that is a `RangeIndex`) and apply slicing to fill your NaN values using `.fillna`:

```
>>> df.loc[4::7] = df.loc[4::7].fillna("?")
>>> df.loc[6::7] = df.loc[6::7].fillna("?")
```

Comment: Your code changes all indexes with actual values to "?".  I only want the code to find where the missing values are and fill them with "?".

Comment: `.fillna` should only change values where there is a null value. Are you seeing the whole dataframe (`print(df)`) or just the selected rows (`print(df.loc[4::7])` or `print(df.loc[6::7])`)?

Comment: I meant the selected rows are changed into "?". But this is not what I want. From the question above, I stated that there will only be one set of rows with the missing values. I need the code the identify where this set of rows is in the df and fill only the two rows that are identified with "?".

Comment: Your code identified all sets of rows with and without the values and fill them all with "?". I want to keep the sets of rows with values that are greater than 0 and find the set of rows with null values, fill the null rows with "?".

Comment: Did you include this part? `df.loc[4::7]` it should only select the fourth row of each group of 7 rows. It should not modify other rows.

Comment: Hi, I meant I only need the 4th and 6th rows of one and only one of the groups of 7 rows to be filled with "?". Not all 4th and 6th rows of all groups of 7 rows. To find one particular group of 7 rows, I need some code that can identify which one of the groups of 7 rows has missing values at the 4th and 6th locations.

Comment: @CYU1 I've updated my answer to match your expected behaviour

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are the G!